# Get all roots of nonlinear equations by using GEKKO

Tags: python, gekko

With an example of nonlinear equations below:

```
x+2y=0
x^2+y^2=1
```

it's pretty obvious the equation has 2 roots.

[image: Roots of the equations]

However, I can only get 1 root by using GEKKO, changing the initial value of `x,y` can get another one.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()

# first solution
x,y = [m.Var(1) for i in range(2)]
m.Equations([x+2*y==0,x**2+y**2==1])
m.solve(disp=False)
print(x.value,y.value)

# second solution
x.value=-1
y.value=-1
m.solve(disp=False)
print(x.value,y.value)
```

```
Solutions:
[0.894427191] [-0.4472135955]
[-0.894427191] [0.4472135955]
```

How can get all roots at the same time?

Comment: Remember to show your code, if you have questions about code not doing what you thought it would do.

Comment: Added a code example and figure to show the multiple roots.

Answer (score 3):

Gekko has solvers that find local minima. The solution that it finds depends on where you start. This is also the case for fsolve or other equation solvers. One exception is symbolic solutions available with SymPy, however, this requires that the equations are simple enough to generate a closed-form and analytic solution. Here are some examples:

http://apmonitor.com/che263/index.php/Main/PythonSolveEquations

Single Root (Numeric solution):

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x,y,w = [m.Var(1) for i in range(3)]
m.Equations([x**2+y**2==20,y-x**2==0,w+5-x*y==0])
m.solve(disp=False)
print(x.value,y.value,w.value)
```

Multiple Roots (Analytic solution):

```py
import sympy as sym
sym.init_printing()
x,y,z = sym.symbols('x,y,z')
c1 = sym.Symbol('c1')
f = sym.Eq(2*x**2+y+z,1)
g = sym.Eq(x+2*y+z,c1)
h = sym.Eq(-2*x+y,-z)
sym.solve([f,g,h],(x,y,z))
```

*An answer by Professor Hedengren from BYU from the e-mail discussion group.*